# Does a K8s service re-send requests when readinessProbe fails?

Tags: kubernetes

A [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) dispatches to multiple replicas of a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) (default round-robin).

The backend instances temporarily have to go offline, i.e. they will close their port 80, take some time, and then open the port again.

`deployment.yaml` is using [`readinessProbe`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) to regularly check which backend instances are ready to serve requests.

But what happens in the following scenario?

```
1) readiness check backend A: OK
2) backend A goes offline
3) requests to service is forwarded to backend A
4) readiness check backend A: fail
```

Will the service send the request again but to another backend instance, or is it lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of Service.

If the Service is a ClusterIP or NodePort, it's instantiated as iptables rules. Packets destined for the now offline pod will be undeliverable, causing the request to timeout.

If the Service is a LoadBalancer, the implementation is an application, like nginx or an equivalent. It will watch for timeouts, and generally speaking- though dependent on configuration- will retry, allowing the request to make it to an online pod.